# Compiling ICU for Android: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token

Tags: android, android-ndk, icu

In putil.cpp there is a call to U_INTERNAL UVoidFunction* U_EXPORT2, but UVoidFunction is somehow not being defined because of U_ENABLE_DYLOAD. When I attempt to set U_ENABLE_DYLOAD=1, I get "warning: U_ENABLE_DYLOAD" redefined.

```
/home/tim/icu49/icu/source/common/putil.cpp:2253: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
```

**Update** Appears to be fixed by declaring --enable-dyload=yes in configuration. But not sure if this is what I should be doing.

Comment: I think you filed a bug against this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by declaring --enable-dyload=yes.